# How can I allow singleton constructor re-entry/pass-over in VS2017?

Tags: c++, singleton, visual-studio-2017

I've been porting some c++ app from Visual Studio 2013 to Visual Studio 2017. Aside from the plethora of new warnings that I had to fix, the compilation and linking went okay.

However, when *running* the app, it 'stalled' when trying to re-enter the constructor of a singleton (when successive function calls form a loop back to the constructor). It seems that this behaviour was okay in VS2013, but is no longer valid in VS2017. There is no error message.

*I'm aware of all the bad things related to singletons, and that there should at least not be loops. The question is not there.*

**Is there a way to tell the VS2017 compiler that I'd like to shoot myself in the foot, and allow the same behaviour that was there in VS2013?**

I don't have access to the code that causes this behaviour because it comes from a third-party library, this is why I can't 'just fix it', unfortunately.

Here is an example which works in VS2013, but doesn't work in VS2017:

## main.cpp

```
#include "Singleton.h";

int 
main( void )
{

  std::cout << "let's do this!" << std::endl;
  int two = Singleton::GetReference().getTwo();
  std::cout << "ok" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

## Singleton.h

```
#pragma once

class Stuff;

class Singleton
{
public:
  static Singleton& GetReference();

  int getTwo() { return 2; }

private:
  Singleton();

  Stuff* stuff;
};
```

## Singleton.cpp

```
#include "Singleton.h"
#include "Stuff.h"

Singleton& 
Singleton::GetReference() { 
  static Singleton theInstance; 
  return theInstance; 
}

Singleton::Singleton()
{
  stuff = new Stuff();
}
```

## Stuff.h

```
#pragma once

class Stuff
{
public:
  Stuff();
private:
  int two;
};
```

## Stuff.cpp

```
#include "Stuff.h"
#include "Singleton.h"

Stuff::Stuff()
{ 
  two = Singleton::GetReference().getTwo();
}
```

In the code above, when step-by-step debugging, the first time we get on the line `static Singleton theInstance;` will work as expected, but the second time, a <kbd>F11</kbd> will go to the file `thread_safe_statics.cpp`, into the method `extern "C" void __cdecl _Init_thread_header(int* const pOnce)`. A <kbd>Shift+F11</kbd> will exit the method and the program will wait indefinitely at the line specified (observed when pausing the program from the debugger).

---

PS

This issue probably occurs in Visual Studio 2015 too, as the documentation linked from the accepted answer mentions VS2015.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: By what kind of logic you want to allow singleton to access itself from its own constructor?

Comment: move the access to getTwo() from constructor of Stuff::Stuff to some function init. Call this function using call_once in the getInstance after the instance is constructed and pass the value of getTwo to it.

Comment: @VTT As mentioned in the post, I don't have access to the code, it is from a third party library (OpenAL, in this case). I'm aware that it is a very bad idea.

Comment: @tobi303 There is no error message; it's really just a behaviour.

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky There would be many ways to fix it if I had access to the faulty singleton code, but I don't, unfortunately. This is why I'm asking if there is a way to do this with the compiler.

Comment: Constructor of Singleton requires that its own constructor has finished...

Comment: Which part do you have access ?

Comment: You can compile it in VS2017 using original toolchain of VS2013 - without upgrading the project

Comment: And which part of OpenAl performs this? Maybe you should turn this into OpenAl-specific problem question?

Comment: @Jarod42 I guess I have access to the code that uses the library.

Comment: @VTT I thought about it, but after fixing that, there might be the same issue with another library. (Another singleton not yet initialized.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/Zc:threadSafeInit-
```

The general "Conformance" page is [MSDN: Conformance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-conformance), which details which new features you can disable.

I needed the code for sizedDealloc, where my new compiler was creating a sized new operator for a library which broke older compiled expectations.

As this is a compile flag, at least some of the code would be in your control, and you should be able to unravel the beast.

The constructor `Stuff::Stuff` is calling a function on an incompletely constructed object.

That would create "Undefined behavior".  If the value "2" is not set till the end of the constructor (for example).

Probably the Singleton needs to be split into 2, one which delivers the early static data (e.g. 2).

The second which delivers the held object Stuff.  Stuff would only rely on the first, which would break the deadlock.

Alternatively, a second constructor to `Stuff` which told it which object to use, and was called from the `Singleton::Singleton`

The MSDN article to disable "Magic Statics" [MSDN : disable threadsafe static initialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-threadsafeinit-thread-safe-local-static-initialization)